# Specify a fallback file for a broken symbolic link

Tags: debian, filesystems, symlink

I want to create a symlink, `foo.txt`, needed at system startup, to another file, `bar.txt` on a different mount point. The mounted partitions are different physical drives as well.

```
ln -s /baz/bar.txt /foo.txt
```

**EDIT:**

So far no problem. The Symlink is created and is valid. The question relates to what will happen when partition at `/bar` disappears.

**/EDIT**

My dilemma is this, the partition mounted at `/baz` may not be present at startup.

My question -> To avoid obvious problems, can I specify a fall back file *at the filesystem level* that the symlink will resolve to rather than simply breaking? Or am i stuck doing this at the application level?

Using Debian linux on an ext4 (the default for the latest release of Debian) filesystem FWIW.

Comment: create a file /baz/bar.txt when the filesystem is not mounted?

Comment: no. sorry if i was unclear. The file will exist at /baz/bar.txt already. It just may or may not be mounted when I need it.

Comment: Make the replacement file /baz/bar.txt while the filesystem is NOT mounted. When /baz gets it's additional filesystem, this file will be below it and when the mounted filesystem has bar.txt, this will seem to replace the other file of below...

Comment: ...and I think this is not ext4-FS specific, so the /ext4 tag seems misleading...

Comment: Great this works! I'll pull the ext4 tag. If you make your suggestion an answer i'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the replacement file /baz/bar.txt while the filesystem is NOT mounted.

When /baz gets it's additional filesystem, this file will be below it and when the mounted filesystem has bar.txt, this will seem to replace the other file of below...